# WP Rest API. Problems with creating endpoints

Tags: wordpress, rest, plugins

There were problems trying to create endpoints. I made a plugin and classes for registering paths and endpoints, but when I try to add new endpoints, the method does not change. Everything is interpreted as GET. For verification added to function.php.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init',     function ()  {
        register_rest_route('museum-funds/v1', '/test',array(
            array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'callback' => function(){
                return 'Test';
            },
        )));
    }
```

As a result, I get the answer:

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "Подходящий маршрут для URL и метода запроса не найден",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

But at the same time, if you send a Get request by the method, then everything works. Can someone tell me what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a syntax error in you code. I have fixed it!

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ()  {
register_rest_route('museum-funds/v1', '/test',
    array(
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'callback' => function(){
                return 'Test';
            },
        )
    )
);
});
```

Add it is giving the result as expected!